# CSS styling stopping form submit button from appearing

Tags: html, css, button

I'm trying to adapt code from https://codepen.io/hesguru/pen/BaybqXv to make a reactive star rating form with a submit button that I can pass to my python back-end. However, I cannot get the submit button to appear, I understand it's probably because of the CSS but haven't been able to work out how to fix it. [(This is how it currently appears)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LlcL4.png) How can I get the submit button to appear and work?

```css
.rate {
    float: left;
    height: 46px;
    padding: 0 10px;
}
.rate:not(:checked) > input {
    position:absolute;
    top:-9999px;
}
.rate:not(:checked) > label {
    float:right;
      overflow:hidden;
    white-space:nowrap;
    cursor:pointer;
    font-size:30px;
    color:#ccc;
}
.rate:not(:checked) > label:before {
    content: '★ ';
}
.rate > input:checked ~ label {
    color: #ffc700;
}
.rate:not(:checked) > label:hover,
.rate:not(:checked) > label:hover ~ label {
    color: #deb217;
}
.rate > input:checked + label:hover,
.rate > input:checked + label:hover ~ label,
.rate > input:checked ~ label:hover,
.rate > input:checked ~ label:hover ~ label,
.rate > label:hover ~ input:checked ~ label {
    color: #c59b08;
} width:1em;
```

```html
<form action="/r" method="POST" class="rate">
    <input type="radio" id="star5" name="rate" value="5" />
    <label for="star5" title="5">5 stars</label>
    <input type="radio" id="star4" name="rate" value="4" />
    <label for="star4" title="4">4 stars</label>
    <input type="radio" id="star3" name="rate" value="3" />
    <label for="star3" title="3">3 stars</label>
    <input type="radio" id="star2" name="rate" value="2" />
    <label for="star2" title="2">2 stars</label>
    <input type="radio" id="star1" name="rate" value="1" />
    <label for="star1" title="1">1 star</label>
    <input type="submit" id="sub" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Looking at the code snippet, everything looks fine, doesn't it? Maybe you'll need to add some mot CSS code to show us your problem more clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you describe is caused by this selector:

```
.rate:not(:checked)>input
```

This will select *all* `<input>` elements within the `.rate` `<form>` element (which itself can never match the the `:checked` pseudo-class), regardless of the type of the `<input>`.

If you amend that line to the following:

```
.rate > input[type=radio]
```

Then it will match only those `<input>` elements which match `type="radio"`; and also remove the (entirely pointless pseudo-class): `:not(:checked)` since a `<form>` element can — and *should* — never match that selector:

```css
.rate {
  float: left;
  height: 46px;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.rate > input[type=radio] {
  position: absolute;
  top: -9999px;
}

.rate:not(:checked)>label {
  float: right;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #ccc;
}

.rate:not(:checked)>label:before {
  content: '★ ';
}

.rate>input:checked~label {
  color: #ffc700;
}

.rate:not(:checked)>label:hover,
.rate:not(:checked)>label:hover~label {
  color: #deb217;
}

.rate>input:checked+label:hover,
.rate>input:checked+label:hover~label,
.rate>input:checked~label:hover,
.rate>input:checked~label:hover~label,
.rate>label:hover~input:checked~label {
  color: #c59b08;
  width: 1em;
}
```

```html
<form action="/r" method="POST" class="rate">
  <input type="radio" id="star5" name="rate" value="5" />
  <label for="star5" title="5">5 stars</label>
  <input type="radio" id="star4" name="rate" value="4" />
  <label for="star4" title="4">4 stars</label>
  <input type="radio" id="star3" name="rate" value="3" />
  <label for="star3" title="3">3 stars</label>
  <input type="radio" id="star2" name="rate" value="2" />
  <label for="star2" title="2">2 stars</label>
  <input type="radio" id="star1" name="rate" value="1" />
  <label for="star1" title="1">1 star</label>
  <input type="submit" id="sub" value="Submit">
</form>
```